# Possible combinations of letters

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I have an example in my lecture where I have the letters: A,A,A,B,B,C,C,C and I need to give the possible combinations.
$$
\frac{8!}{3!\cdot3!\cdot2!} = 560
$$
In one part of the exercise I have to give the number of arrangements where 3 A's are next to each other. From my understanding, I would consider all the A's as 1, resulting in 6 "letters", therefore 6!
$$
\frac{6!}{3!\cdot2!\cdot1!} = 60
$$
The solution given in the script is $70$ possibilities.
Which one is correct?
And wouldn't I need to multiply with the possibilities in which the 3 A's can be organized?

Comment: Both your answers are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Your initial calculation is correct if by "combinations" you mean the number of permutations (= "arrangements") of the letters. I agree also with your second calculation, if I have understood the question correctly. As the A's are being treated as identical letters there is no need to multiply by $3!$ so 60 is correct.